# Margin and spacing between widgets

Tags: c++, qt, layout

I would like to manage the space between my widgets, vertically and horizontal.

Here is a picture that illustrate what I want:

[image: 4 rectangular widgets in a container widgets with spacing in between]

When I click on the red point, I want to reduce/extend the spaces where the red lines are (vertically).

When I click on the blue point, I want to reduce/extend the spaces where the blue lines are (horizontally).

My architecture is like that:

A main Widget with a layout, which contains the left/right arrow buttons and a QWidget for all the white views.

This QWidget contains a QGridLayout. In this QGridLayout I have the "left", "back"… widgets (in white on the screenshot).

- QWidget with a layout

  - left arrow
  - right arrow
  - QWidget with a QGridLayout (GRIDLAYOUT)

    - QWidget with a VBoxLayout and 2 labels inside. (`VIEW`)

I tried to set the `VIEW->setContentsMargins();`, but the white rectangle stays the same, only the spacing inside this rectangle change (between the border and the "left" label for example (1 and 2 on the screen)).

I also tried to set the `GRIDLAYOUT->setContentsMargins();`, but this time only the spacing of number 3 and 4 on the screen are changing.

Obviously, there is the same behaviour for the horizontal resizing (the blue marks on the screenshot).

The spacing doesn't allow managing vertical and horizontal spacing separately.

How can I manage this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For managing the space inbetween the white rects you can easily use

```
QGridLayout()::setHorizontalSpacing(int spacing);
QGridLayout()::setVerticalSpacing(int spacing);
```

This will set up the space between the white rects but not the space between white rect and border of upper widget. For these you will have to use  (inherited from QLayout):

```
QGridLayout()::setContentsMargins ( int left, int top, int right, int bottom )
```